# Postgres Window function

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Please provide some suggestions to solve the problem below with window functions, in postgres.

**Input data:**
111;"2016-01-01 10:00:00";"park"
111;"2016-01-01 10:01:00";"guide"
111;"2016-01-01 10:02:00";"guide"
111;"2016-01-01 10:03:00";"operate"
111;"2016-01-01 10:04:00";"guide"
111;"2016-01-01 10:05:00";"guide"
222;"2016-01-01 10:00:00";"park"
222;"2016-01-01 10:01:00";"guide"
222;"2016-01-01 10:02:00";"guide"
222;"2016-01-01 10:03:00";"operate"
222;"2016-01-01 10:04:00";"guide"
222;"2016-01-01 10:05:00";"guide"

**Output Required:**

111;"2016-01-01 10:00:00";"park";1
**111;"2016-01-01 10:01:00";"guide";2

111;"2016-01-01 10:02:00";"guide";2**
111;"2016-01-01 10:03:00";"operate";3
**111;"2016-01-01 10:04:00";"guide";4

111;"2016-01-01 10:05:00";"guide";4**
222;"2016-01-01 10:00:00";"park";1
**222;"2016-01-01 10:01:00";"guide";2

222;"2016-01-01 10:02:00";"guide";2**
222;"2016-01-01 10:03:00";"operate";3
**222;"2016-01-01 10:04:00";"guide";4

222;"2016-01-01 10:05:00";"guide";4**

code for Input data:
create temp table input_tb (id int, date timestamp, category text);
insert into input_tb values (111, '2016-01-01:10:00:00', 'park');
insert into input_tb values (111, '2016-01-01:10:01:00', 'guide');
insert into input_tb values (111, '2016-01-01:10:02:00', 'guide');
insert into input_tb values (111, '2016-01-01:10:03:00', 'operate');
insert into input_tb values (111, '2016-01-01:10:04:00', 'guide');
insert into input_tb values (111, '2016-01-01:10:05:00', 'guide');
insert into input_tb values (222, '2016-01-01:10:00:00', 'park');
insert into input_tb values (222, '2016-01-01:10:01:00', 'guide');
insert into input_tb values (222, '2016-01-01:10:02:00', 'guide');
insert into input_tb values (222, '2016-01-01:10:03:00', 'operate');
insert into input_tb values (222, '2016-01-01:10:04:00', 'guide');
insert into input_tb values (222, '2016-01-01:10:05:00', 'guide');

Thanks for your help.

Suresh

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  id, date, category,
        SUM(swap)  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                (LAG(category) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) IS DISTINCT FROM category)::INTEGER swap
        FROM    input_tb
        ) q
```

See the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1aa93e/5)